# winsock2 cannot bind a socket

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I'm new to winapi(winsocket2). Here is my full code (I can't otherwise as my program does compile however does not seem to work(does not bind a socket-bind function return -1)).

```
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
WSADATA sData;
SOCKADDR_IN linker;
SOCKET sSocket;
int main()
{
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,3),&sData)!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot startup WINsocket";
        return -1;
    }
    cout<<"\tWINsocket loaded!\n\n";
    if(sSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid socket.";
        return -1;
    }
    cout<<"\tSocket loaded!\n\n";
    linker.sin_family=AF_INET;
    linker.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    linker.sin_port=htons(3490);
    memset( &( linker.sin_zero ), '\0', 8 );
    char yes='1';
    if( setsockopt( sSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof( yes ) ) == - 1 )
    {
        perror( "setsockopt" );
       exit(1);
    }
    if(bind(sSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&linker,sizeof(linker))==SOCKET_ERROR)
        cout<<"lol";

    cout<<"\tSocket succesfully binded!\n\n";
    listen(sSocket,10);
}
```

I tried this, pasting right before if bind

```
char yes='1';
      if( setsockopt( sSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof( yes ) ) == - 1 )
      {
      perror( "setsockopt" );
      exit(1);
      }
```

but this func just prints out
    setsockopt: No error 
and quit.
 thanks for help

Comment: To get WSAErrors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: 10038 error it tell me that I'm operating on a non socket, but I am

Comment: `perror` is based on `errno`, which obviously also fails with WinSock. Note that you can get textual error messages using `FormatMessage` instead. When working with WinSock, keep in mind that it is not a complete reimplementation of the Berkeley socket API, always consult the MSDN documentation when in doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The `SO_REUSEADDR` option expects a paramter of type `BOOL`, which is a typedef for `int`.  I suspect passing a `char` is causing the problem: `setsockopt()` will refuse to assign the option unless the last parameter's size matches the expected size, which is not true in your case (`sizeof(char) != sizeof(BOOL)`).

In other words, you can change your code to this:

```
BOOL yes = 1;
if( setsockopt( sSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&yes, sizeof( yes ) ) == - 1 )
{
   perror( "setsockopt" );
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I do that exactly and I get an error  "cannot conver bool* to const char* for 4th argument

Comment: You have to use a type-cast: `setsockopt(..., (char*)&yes, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(sSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)==INVALID_SOCKET)
```

Parentheses problem. Try this:

```
if((sSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))==INVALID_SOCKET)
```